# When i compile a program that contains std::size() , compiler showing an error, can anyone help me to solve it?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

this is the program: i am attching screenshot of the error

[image]

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
 int x[]= {23,4,66,83,45,65,78,8900};

for(int i =0;i < std::size(x); i++){
  std::cout<<"Number "<<i<<" "<<x[i]<<std::endl;
}
}
```

a solution for this error

Comment: `sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])`

Comment: It means your compiler is either too old or you need to specify the standard c++17 or newer.

Comment: std::size is a C++17 feature (try to enable it with -std=c++17).

Comment: gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) this is my gcc version

Comment: I believe gcc-9.4 won't default to `-std=c++17` you will have to add it to your compiler flags.

Answer (score 0):

`std::size` is defined in a number of headers, but iostream is not one of them.

```
Defined in header <array>
Defined in header <deque>
Defined in header <forward_list>
Defined in header <iterator>
Defined in header <list>
Defined in header <map>
Defined in header <regex>
Defined in header <set>
Defined in header <span> (since C++20)
Defined in header <string>
Defined in header <string_view>
Defined in header <unordered_map>
Defined in header <unordered_set>
Defined in header <vector>
```